# joomla get article latest image and title with php

Tags: php, joomla3.0

hi guys thanks a lot for your help.

I am trying to code a little php snippet in joomla via which i can just the latest image of the latest article and place it in on the homepage. All i want is that everytime an article is posted in a specific category which is the latest article and the image of that latest article should be pulled and I can show it some place. So basically I want 5 categories and everytime we post a new article we can call its latest article title and image and show it on the homepage in my own css based design.

```
// Article Image 
$article = JTable::getInstance("content"); 
$article->load(JRequest::getInt("id")); // Get Article ID 
$article_images = $article->get("images"); // Get image parameters 
$pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart 
// Print the image 
echo "<img src='" . $pictures->{'image_intro'} . "' alt='" . $pictures->   {'image_intro_alt'} . "'>";
```

Any help in the right direction would be great. Thanks so much guys :)

Comment: what does it print when you write `var_dump($pictures->image_intro);`?

Comment: You should be able to do this with the articles news flash module, modifying the layout.